# music app problem

Tags: settings, release-juno, music

My problem is whenever I click the play icon on the sound tab, the music will not start. I have to go to the app every time to play the songs. Shouldn't the songs just start by pressing the play button?
[image: here is what am talking about]

I don't know if this is normal or not because if it's normal that's just annoying.

And yes all of my songs are in the music directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... I think it's normal, it also works like that in my case. I think that works that way, if you're reproducing something that control works.

cya.